# puppet syntax multiple node includes different roles

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Is it possible to set multiple nodes to includes different roles? Like this **node_modules.pp**:

```
node 'puppet-appserver.dev' {
  include role::app_server
}

node 'puppet-dbserver.dev' {
  include role::db_server
}
```

Comment: please can you explain your question?

Answer (score 0):

On short answer yes!

All file with .pp extension in directory manifests on you control repo will be read and all nodes declaration will be executed